# Draw circles and other shapes with SpriteKit Scene Editor?

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, skscene

Tutorials online allude to creating circles and other shapes using the SpriteKit Scene Editor. One such example is this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/118225/introduction-sprite-kit-scene-editor.

However, the only type of shape node available in the Object Library is a square shape.

How do you use the Object Library to create other shapes besides squares?

Answer (score 3):

As of right now, square is your only option.  Perhaps in the next version they will allow more shapes,  but as of right now, I would avoid using SKShapeNode's because they are extremely buggy

Source:  XCode scene editor, only option is square,  none of the tabs allow this to change or be subclassed

Comment: Where is the source from? Link?

Comment: What source? Open up xcode spritekit scene editor and look yourself

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought when you said "Source:", you were quoting someone. You were saying the source is the scene editor itself and you are correct

Comment: Still true in 2020

Comment: Square is only option, and you can't even specify it's size, only the scale.

Comment: Still true in 2024

Answer (score 1):

> An **SKShapeNode** object draws a shape defined by a Core Graphics path.
>
> The graphics path is a collection of straight lines and curves that
> can define either open or closed subpaths. You can specify separate
> rendering behavior for the filled and stroked portion of the path.
> Each part can be rendered using either a solid color or a texture; if
> you need to render more sophisticated effects, you can also use a
> custom shader.
>
> Shape nodes are useful for content that cannot be easily decomposed
> into simple textured sprites. Shape nodes are also very useful for
> building and displaying debugging information on top of your game
> content. However, the SKSpriteNode class offers higher performance
> than this class, so use shape nodes sparingly.
>
> Creating a shape node from a path shows an example of how to create a
> shape node. The example creates a circle with a blue interior and a
> white outline. The path is created and attached to the shape node’s
> path property.

You can find more details to the Apple official [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/)

This is the actual available init methods from the sources:

```
/* Create a Shape Node using a CGPathRef, optionally centered at the Node's origin. */
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public convenience init(path: CGPath)
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public convenience init(path: CGPath, centered: Bool)
    
    /* Create a Shape Node representing a Rect. */
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public convenience init(rect: CGRect)
    
    /* Create a Shape Node representing a rect centered at the Node's origin. */
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public convenience init(rectOfSize size: CGSize)
    
    /* Create a Shape Node representing a rounded rect with a corner radius */
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public convenience init(rect: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat)
    
    /* Create a Shape Node representing a rounded rect with a corner radius centered at the Node's origin. */
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public convenience init(rectOfSize size: CGSize, cornerRadius: CGFloat)
    
    /* Create a Shape Node representing an circle centered at the Node's origin. */
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public convenience init(circleOfRadius radius: CGFloat)
    
    /* Create a Shape Node representing an Ellipse inscribed within a Rect */
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public convenience init(ellipseInRect rect: CGRect)
    
    /* Create a Shape Node representing an Ellipse inscribed within a Rect centered at the Node's origin. */
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public convenience init(ellipseOfSize size: CGSize)
    
    /* Create a Shape Node representing an a series of Points interpreted as line segments */
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public convenience init(points: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>, count numPoints: Int)
    
    /* Create a Shape Node representing a smoothed spline that passes through a series of Points */
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public convenience init(splinePoints points: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>, count numPoints: Int)
```

As you can see you can create non only squares but also irregular polygon using for example the a custom `CGPath`.

A typical example is this below:

```
let shape = SKShapeNode()
shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: -128, y: -128, width: 256, height: 256), cornerRadius: 64).CGPath
shape.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(frame))
shape.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
shape.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
shape.lineWidth = 10
addChild(shape)
```

**P.S.**:
Could occur some bugs in memory caused by `SKShapeNode` during development but nothing that would prevent you to test, create and publish a game, many games on the market make use of `SKShapeNode` without problems , you have to simply be more careful in the code without abusing of it.